# Example of no non-constant meromorphic functions

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This is a basic question but I have found it annoyingly hard to find an answer (which means its incredibly trivial or non-trivial!)

Are there examples of compact complex manifolds (of dimension at least 2) which do not admit any global, non-constant, meromorphic functions?

Of course this question can be phrased in a number of ways. For one, is there an example of a compact complex manifold which does not admit a rational map into a projective space? Equivalently, is there an example of a compact complex manifold which does not admit a linear system with a base locus of at least codimension 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

The generic Hopf surfaces (surfaces diffeomorphic to $S^3\times S^1$, or equivalently $\mathbb{C}^2-0$ quotient by an infinite cyclic group $\Gamma\subset GL(2,\mathbb{C})$) are such an example.
Basically if $\Gamma$ is generated by a matrix $A$ with distinct eigenvalues (WLOG $A=\operatorname{\mathrm{diag}}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$), then the existence of non-constant meromorphic function $f/g$ gives two holomorphic functions $f,g$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by Hartog's and hence using $\Gamma$-invariance and considering lowest order terms when you clear denominators, you get $\lambda_1^m=\lambda_2^n$ for some $m,n$.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Do you happen to know any reference for this (and others)?

Comment: Are there Kahler examples?

Comment: I think it is in Shafarevich's book, if not you can look at R. O. Well's recent paper (arXiv:1803.07611).

Comment: Ha I don't know how I didn't manage to find that paper! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the late ping, but is there anything intelligent we can say about divisors on a complex manifold with no nonconstant meromorphic functions? Clearly, the lack of meromorphic functions makes rational equivalence trivial. Does this mean that the divisor class group becomes huge?